# How to split my library in modules?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, closures

I'm writing a JS library that day by day is getting too big to maintain, so I want to split it in "modules", then process them with Grunt to produce a single JS file.

I have troubles understanding how things work when there are private and public functions involved. Here is a very basic example on how my library is built:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var MyLib = window.MyLib = {};

    var MyEnum = {
        ONE: 1,
        TWO: 2
    };

    MyLib.login = function() { doUserLogin(); };

    function doUserLogin () {
        // ...
        showPopup("ok!");
    }

    function showPopup (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
})();
```

This way:

- `MyLib` is visible from the outside using `MyLib.<whatever>`
- `MyEnum` is visibile only **inside** this library
- `login()` is callable from the outside, with `MyLib.login()`. This function internally calls a **private** method `doUserLogin()`
- From the outside, the user must **not** be able to call `doUserLogin()` and `showPopup()`

I think that I could create a main JS with the declaration of MyLib object, public methods like `login()` and local constants like `MyEnum`, plus two modules (namespaces?) `/users` and `/popups`:

- `users.js` contains the definition of `doUserLogin()`
- `popups.js` contains everything related to the creation of popups

The previous pattern must be still valid in this situation. So, `doUserLogin()` can call `showPopup()` but both of them **cannot be callable from outside the library**.

Can you show a basic example on how to split it?

Comment: Even if you could split this with Grunt I wouldn't do that (I wouldn't even know where to start tbh). You should split it manually.

Comment: Can you describe why you wouldn't do that? Keep in mind that my real lib is far bigger than the example.
Also, I should split it manually but then I want a tool that produces a single .js file

Comment: It's easy for Grunt to combine modules into a single file, much more complicated to split up a single file into multiple modules.

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured out that my question was not so clear. My intent is to **manually** split this library in modules, then give them to Grunt in order to automatically produce an unique JS file.
I've edited the question.

Comment: Read about CommonJS and Browserify.